# When executing selenium code getting failsafe issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at Automation/LXMedicalPackage.OpenURL.main(OpenURL.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 4 more
```

I install the  failsafe jar what didn't work it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well, in my case, I am using modular Java 17.

I solved this issue by adding `dev.failsafe.core` module as required. Try followings:

1. If you are using modular Java, your module-info.java file must be as below:

```java
module module.name {
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.api;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver;
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver;
    requires dev.failsafe.core; // add this line
}
```

2. Try to upgrade selenium version or find appropriate browser driver.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13670) on selenium GitHub repo, you can check that as well for more info.